# How to keep website available to some users oonly using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

my website is under construction and i would like to show the website to my friends ,And deny to all users. i used particular ips in htaccess files,but ip is not static . Is there any way to keep mac address ? or any way

Comment: Make the root of your website as password protected and then pass the login information to your friends. Check this article: http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2009/07/password-protect-directory-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't match against a MAC Address using directives in an htaccess file. You could either

1. Put a password on your actual content and everyone without the password gets forwarded to an "Under Construction" page (possibly using `ErrorDocument` 403 /under_construction.html`)
2. Look for a special query string that you can give out to only your friends:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !special_var=my_buddies
   RewriteRule ^ /under_construction.html [R=301,L]
   ```

   So here, any url without the `special_var=my_buddies` query string ( http://hostname.com/some/content.php?special_var=my_buddies ) gets redirected to the under construction page
3. You can do something similar by setting a cookie. Create a small landing page called something like `/my_buddies.php` that simply does a `set_cookie()` call to create a `my_buddies` cookie (doesn't have to be php, and the cookie can be called anything). Then do something similar as the query string:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !my_buddies
   RewriteRule ^ /under_construction.html [R=301,L]
   ```

   Essentially the same thing. If there's no `my_buddies` in the cookie string, redirect to the under construction page.

There's probably other ways to get do something like this, but can't think of anything off the top of my head.